# Ocultar un modal y mostrar otro en bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

No se como hacer para ocultar un modal de bootstrap una vez hagas clic en un botón, a través de una función *javascript*, para automáticamente mostrar otro diferente.

La cosa es que con `modal.hide` soy capaz de ocultarlo, pero no de hacer desaparecer el fondo oscuro del modal, que no deja interactuar con la pagina.

En cambio con `modal.dispose`, desaparece el fondo, pero no del modal en sí, y cuando combino los dos fallan.

**¿Cómo se haría para hacerlo desaparecer totalmente y hacer aparecer otro?**

Aquí está el código de la página.

```js
function validar(){
  const Username= document.getElementById("Username").value;
  const password= document.getElementById("input-pass").value;
  const modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(uploads);
  const passwordreal=`e`;
if(Username=='e'){
  if(password==passwordreal){
    modal.hide();
  }else{
    //location.href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBqw818mQ1E'
  }
}else{
  //location.href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2E7yADUtwk8'
}
}
```

```css
:root{
    --input-color: #80868B;
  --border-color: #DADCE0;
}
body {
    background-image: url("https://64.media.tumblr.com/bd1b0d977b3e43cc5645297d5322662c/tumblr_ndyybljlWc1rvnh7zo1_r1_500.gif");
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
  }
              /* Centrar elemento dentro de main */
  .main {
   position: absolute;
   margin: auto;
   left: 0; right: 0;
   top: 0; bottom: 0;
   width: 1404px/*550px*/;
   height: 658px/*315px*/; line-height: 50px; /* Con «line-height» con el mismo valor numérico de la altura centras horizontalmente el texto */
  
  }
  .video{
      width: 1370px;
   height: 770px;
  }
  .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    /* top: 0; */
    bottom: 0;
    width: 3vw;
    height: 97vh;
}
.input {
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--container-color);
  padding: 1.35rem 1.25rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: .75rem;
}

.input__lock, .input__icon {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  z-index: 1;
}


.input__lock, .input__password {
  color: var(--white-color);
}

.input__icon {
  color: var(--first-color);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5vw;
  top: 1.5vh;
}

.input__password {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.input__password::placeholder {
  color: var(--white-color);
}

.input__overlay {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: var(--white-color);
  position: absolute;
  right: .9rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

/* Transition effect */
.overlay-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  right: 0;
}

.overlay-content ~ .input__lock {
  color: var(--container-color);
}

.overlay-content ~ .input__password,
.overlay-content ~ .input__password::placeholder {
  color: var(--text-color);
}
.form{
  width: 360px;
  padding: 4rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
.form__title{
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
.form__div{
  position: relative;
  height: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
.input__icon {
  color: var(--first-color);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form__input{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
  border-radius: .5rem;
  outline: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: none;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}
.form__label{
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
  top: 1rem;
  padding: 0 .25rem;
  background-color: var(--bs-dark-rgb);
  color: var(--input-color);
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  transition: .3s;
}
.form__button{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: .75rem 2rem;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  border-radius: .5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s;
}
.form__button:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 10px 36px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}

/*Input focus mover arriba label*/
.form__input:focus + .form__label{
  top: -.5rem;
  left: .8rem;
  color: var(--first-color);
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  font-weight: 500;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #212529;
}

/*Input focus mantener arriba label*/
.form__input:not(:placeholder-shown).form__input:not(:focus)+ .form__label{
  top: -.5rem;
  left: .8rem;
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  font-weight: 500;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #212529;
}

/*Input focus*/
.form__input:focus{
  border: 1.5px solid var(--first-color);
}

.bx2 {
  font-family: boxicons!important;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  /*line-height: 3.5;*/
  text-rendering: auto;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  text-transform: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  position: absolute;
  /* right: 23px; */
  left: 19rem;
  top: 0.80rem;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.img-content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
}

.img-content:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*====================================================================================*/

.box2 img {
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spectral+SC:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
        <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
        <title>Prueba</title>
        <!--=============== BOXICONS ===============-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <div class="icon">
            <a href="#uploads" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#uploads"><ion-icon name="reorder-four-outline" size="large"></ion-icon></a>

        </div>
        <div class="main">
            
        </div>
        <!--Modal-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="uploads" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
            <div class="modal-dialog bg-dark">
              <div class="modal-content bg-dark">
                <div class="modal-header bg-dark">
                  <h5 class="modal-title bg-dark" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 80rem;">
                        <h3 style="color:#ffffff" class="card-header"><i class="far fa-image" aria-hidden="true"></i>Login</h3>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p id="demo"></p>
                          <form id="Formulario" action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
                              <br>
                              <div class="form__div">
                                <input id="Username" type="text" class="form__input" placeholder=" " autofocus name="Email">
                                <label for="" class="form__label">Username</label>
                              </div>
            
                            <div class="form__div">
                                <div class="input__overlay" id="input-overlay"></div>
                                <input type="password" placeholder=" " class="form__input" id="input-pass" name="Password">
                                <label for="" class="form__label">Password</label>
                                <i class='bx bx-hide input__icon' id="input-icon"></i>
                            </div>
                              <br>
                            <script>
                                /*=============== SHOW / HIDDEN INPUT ===============*/
const showHiddenInput = (inputOverlay, inputPass, inputIcon) =>{
    const overlay = document.getElementById(inputOverlay),
          input = document.getElementById(inputPass),
          iconEye = document.getElementById(inputIcon)
          
    iconEye.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        // Change password to text
        if(input.type === 'password'){
            // Switch to text
            input.type = 'text'

            // Change icon
            iconEye.classList.add('bx-show')
        }else{
            // Change to password
            input.type = 'password'

            // Remove icon
            iconEye.classList.remove('bx-show')
        }

        // Toggle the overlay
        overlay.classList.toggle('overlay-content')
    })
}

showHiddenInput('input-overlay','input-pass','input-icon')
                            </script>
                              <br>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <button type="submit" onclick="validar()" class="btn btn-outline-light">
                                      <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>Subir Imagen
                                  </button>
                                  
                              </div>
                          </form>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Fin Modal-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema viene dado cuando se intenta cerrar un modal que ha sido creado mediante los atributos `data-bs-` y luego se intenta manipular con javascript directamente, aún usando las funciones de javascript de **bootstrap**.

Al crearse mediante los atributos `data-bs`, en el **DOM** suceden dos cosas más, aparte de mostrar el modal:

1. Se agrega la clase `modal-open` al elemento `<body>`.
2. Se agregan elementos con la clase `modal-backdrop` (normalmente uno, pero podria darse el caso que hubiera más).

Si lo cerramos con `data-bs-dismiss` se consigue revertir todo eso y cerrarse bien todo, pues **bootstrap** mantiene su vinculación correctamente al estar abierto mediante el atributo `data-bs-toggle`.

Pero si lo cerramos con javascript con el método `hide`, aún asignando el objecto mediante una instancia ([getInstance](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#getinstance)), tan solo se cierra el modal, pero tanto la clase `modal-open` como los elementos con la clase `modal-backdrop` permanecen en el DOM. Es como si no los supiera relacionar correctamente (quizás es un bug o quizás su diseño es de ese modo por algo que se me escapa).

En tu caso concreto se puede solucionar de varias maneras, a saber:

## Solución 1. Todo en javascript

Modifica esta línea:

```
<a href="#uploads" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#uploads"><ion-icon name="reorder-four-outline" size="large"></ion-icon></a>
```

por esta otra:

```
<a href="#uploads" onclick="abrirModal('uploads')" ><ion-icon name="reorder-four-outline" size="large"></ion-icon>adasdasd</a>
```

y crea la siguiente función en tu javascript:

```
var myModal

function abrirModal(id) {
  myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById(id), {
    keyboard: false
  })
  myModal.show();
}
```

Eso permitirá descartar el uso de los atributos `data-bs` para mostrar el modal, y al estar todo funcionando con javascript entonces bootstrap relaciona bien todo lo dicho anteriormente.

- Y para cerrarlo ahora si puedes usar esto en cualquier parte que te convenga:

```
myModal.hide();
```

## Solución 2. A lo bruto con jquery

- Ya que has dicho que estas usando jquery, agrega estas lineas cuando quieras cerrarlo:

```
$('#uploads').modal('hide');
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

También se podría hacer con javascript puro y mediante querySelector() y/o querySelectorAll(), pero si vas a usar jquery es más simple de este modo (aunque el uso de jquery representa un tiempo de carga adicional a la página).

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido solucionarlo atreves de instalar la librería jQuery con:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Una vez hecho en el js, añadí el siguiente fragmente justo debajo de las comprobaciones de Username Y Password.

```
$("#uploads").removeClass("fade").modal("hide");
$("#Logintrue").modal("show").addClass("fade");
$("#Salir").on("click", function () {
  $("#Logintrue").removeClass("fade").modal("hide");
  $(".modal-backdrop").fadeOut("slow");
```

Las dos primeras líneas de encargan de cambiar los modals y cuando le das al botón en la "Salir" (#Salir) se ejecuta una función que hace desaparecer el modal y después elimina el fondo oscuro. Aunque después no aparece el fondo oscuro al volver a abrir los modals.